# Do you add your proficiency bonus when throwing a pebble from the Magic Stone cantrip?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, proficiency, attack-roll

Would you add your proficiency bonus to a pebble from the *magic stone* cantrip? The spell description says nothing about it.

The [***magic stone***](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-stone) spell description states (EEPC, p. 20; XGtE, p. 160):

> You touch one to three pebbles and imbue them with magic. You or
>   someone else can make a ranged spell attack with one of the pebbles by
>   throwing it or hurling it with a sling. If thrown, it has a range of
>   60 feet. If someone else attacks with the pebble, that attacker adds
>   your spellcasting ability modifier, not the attacker’s, to the attack
>   roll. On a hit, the target takes bludgeoning damage equal to 1d6 +
>   your spellcasting ability modifier. Hit or miss, the spell then ends
>   on the stone. If you cast this spell again, the spell ends early on
>   any pebbles still affected by it.

Would this be considered an improvised weapon that wouldn't get the proficiency bonus added to the attack?

Answer (score 17):

## Yes, you're making a ranged spell attack

[*Magic stone*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-stone) (*Elemental Evil Player's Companion*, 160) states:

> You [...] can make a ranged spell attack [...]

All creatures are proficient in [ranged] spell attacks, so you are proficient in this one as well. [Chapter 10 of the PHB](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#AttackRolls) covers this:

> Your attack bonus with a spell attack equals your spellcasting ability modifier + your proficiency bonus.

However, *magic stone* has the additional caveat that you use the original caster's modifier:

> If someone else attacks with the pebble, that attacker adds your spellcasting ability modifier, not the attacker’s, to the attack roll.